# Align equations and boxes in itemize environment

Tags: equations, align, tcolorbox, itemize

I'd like to align the three equations.
Furthermore the colored boxes should be aligned 
(start all at the same point on the left side).

My code:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
\usepackage{icomma}
    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Farben ermöglichen

%%% ------ Formel schöner darstellen ------------
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems,skins}
\def\mathunderline#1#2{\color{#1}\underline{{\color{black}#2}}\color{black}}
    
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $\bm{B_{\delta \mathrm{s}}^{2}}$ der $\bm{\nu}$-ten Statorwelle bilden}
        \begin{equation}
        \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
        \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Blue]{\sigma_{\mathrm{n} \nu} = \frac{B_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu}^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} = \frac{\left( \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \cos \left(\nu p \alpha - \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \right)^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} = \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu}^{2}}{4 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( 1 + \cos \left(2 \nu p \alpha - 2 \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big)}
        \label{eq: Statorschwingung}
        \end{equation}
    \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Produkt $\bm{2 \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{s}} \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{r}}}$ der $\bm{\nu}$-ten Statorwelle mit der $\mu$-ten Rotorwelle bilden}
        \begin{equation}
        \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
        \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Gray]{\begin{split}
        \sigma_{n \nu \mu} &= \frac{2 \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} }{2 \cdot\mu_{0}} \\
        &= \frac{2 \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \cos \left(\nu p \alpha - \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} \cdot \cos                    \left(\mu p \alpha - \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right)}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} \\
        &= \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( \Big. \cos \left( (\nu - \mu) p \alpha
        - (1 - \mu) \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \\
        &+ \Big. \cos \left( (\nu + \mu) p \alpha - (1 + \mu) \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big) \end{split}}
        \label{eq: Statorschwingung_2}
        \end{equation}
    \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $\bm{B_{\delta \mathrm{r}}^{2}}$ der $\bm{\mu}$-ten Rotorwelle bilden}
        \begin{equation}
        \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
        \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Green]{\sigma_{\mathrm{n} \mu} = \frac{B_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} = \frac{\left( \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} \cdot \cos \left(\mu p \alpha - \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \right)^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} = \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}^{2}}{4 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( 1 + \cos \left(2 \mu p \alpha - 2 \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big)}
        \label{eq: Statorschwingung_3}
        \end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to achieve (marked in black):
[desired_result.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jic52uhsye3k6pr/itemize.JPG?dl=0)
(could not insert image here due to server error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility with the `fleqn` environment of `nccmath`:

```
    \documentclass[
        pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
        bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
        headlines=2.1,headsepline,
        numbers=noenddot
    ]{scrreprt}

    \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    %%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
    \usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
    \usepackage{icomma}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
    \usepackage{trfsigns}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{xcolor} % Farben ermöglichen

    %%% ------ Formel schöner darstellen ------------
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems,skins}
    \def\mathunderline#1#2{\color{#1}\underline{{\color{black}#2}}\color{black}}

    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $\bm{B_{\delta \mathrm{s}}^{2}}$ der $\bm{\nu}$-ten Statorwelle bilden}
            \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{equation}
            \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
            \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Blue]{\begin{split}\sigma_{\mathrm{n} \nu} = \frac{B_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu}^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} & = \frac{\left( \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \cos \left(\nu p \alpha - \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \right)^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}}\\ & = \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu}^{2}}{4 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( 1 + \cos \left(2 \nu p \alpha - 2 \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big)\end{split}}
            \label{eq: Statorschwingung}
            \end{equation}
            \end{fleqn}
        \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Produkt $\bm{2 \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{s}} \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{r}}}$ der $\bm{\nu}$-ten Statorwelle mit der $\mu$-ten Rotorwelle bilden}
            \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{equation}
            \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
            \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Gray]{\begin{split}
            \sigma_{n \nu \mu} &= \frac{2 \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot B_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} }{2 \cdot\mu_{0}} \\
            &= \frac{2 \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \cos \left(\nu p \alpha - \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} \cdot \cos \left(\mu p \alpha - \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right)}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} \\
            &= \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{s} \nu} \cdot \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( \Big. \cos \left( (\nu - \mu) p \alpha
            - (1 - \mu) \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \\
            &+ \Big. \cos \left( (\nu + \mu) p \alpha - (1 + \mu) \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big) \end{split}}
            \label{eq: Statorschwingung_2}
            \end{equation}
            \end{fleqn}
        \item \textbf{die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $\bm{B_{\delta \mathrm{r}}^{2}}$ 
        der $\bm{\mu}$-ten Rotorwelle bilden}
            \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{equation}
            \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
            \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=Green]{\begin{split}\sigma_{\mathrm{n} \mu} = \frac{B_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}} & = \frac{\left( \hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu} \cdot \cos \left(\mu p \alpha - \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \right)^{2}}{2 \cdot \mu_{0}}\\
             & = \frac{\hat{B}_{\delta \mathrm{r} \mu}^{2}}{4 \cdot \mu_{0}} \cdot \Big( 1 + \cos \left(2 \mu p \alpha - 2 \mu \omega_{\mathrm{el}} t \right) \Big)\end{split}}
            \label{eq: Statorschwingung_3}
            \end{equation}
            \end{fleqn}
    \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!